# Issue with rowspan on pdf creation

Tags: javascript, pdf, jspdf, jspdf-autotable

So, I just recently added the support for rowspan on my pdf creation, as requested by my client. But it's not working as expected.

Following the code on the [example](https://github.com/simonbengtsson/jsPDF-AutoTable/blob/master/examples/examples.js) I added the rowspan, and it works correctly... on the last column. Not so much on the previous ones.

As you can see on this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/CJLopez/6ewqnwty/9/).

A little explanation on how it works... or I intent to make it work.

When creating the json of the table, I store in the value the amount of rows the cell spawns, separating the amount and the value with a *

```
var val = cell
    ? cell.hasChildNodes() && cell.childNodes[0].tagName !== undefined
    ? cell.childNodes[0].textContent + (cell.getAttribute("rowSpan") ? "*" + cell.getAttribute("rowSpan") : '')
    : cell.textContent.trim() 
    : '';
```

When rendering the pdf, on the `drawCell` hook, I review if the value contains a *, so I know it's a cell that spawns rows, so I do a `split` to the value and get the amount of rows it spans and the value that should appear, create the table cell with the correct size and position

```
drawCell: 
       function (cell, data) {
            if (cell.raw === undefined)
                return false;
            if(cell.raw.indexOf("*") > -1) {
                var text = cell.raw.split("*")[0];
                var times = parseInt(cell.raw.split("*")[1]);
                doc.rect(cell.x, cell.y, cell.width, cell.height * times, 'DF');
                doc.autoTableText(text, cell.x + cell.width / 2, cell.y + cell.height * times / 2, {
                    halign: 'center',
                    valign: 'middle'
                });
                return false;
            }
        }
```

Any ideas???

Edit

I just adjusted a little the fiddle, and I'm getting a respectable result

Previously, I was getting missing cells at the end of row where cells spawned rows

[image: Missing cells on spawned rows]

So, instead of ignoring those cells that I'm hiding due to the row spawn, I'm setting their `raw` value to empty string

```
if (cell.raw === undefined)
        cell.raw = '';
```

And now, I'm getting complete grids

[image: Complete grids]

But, then again, the pdf is rendering row lines in the middle of my spawned cells. Looks better, but still, not the desired result. [Here's the updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/CJLopez/qhc1kdyd/), also adjusted for black and white coloring and using the most recent version of jspdf-AutoTable

I already setting the cells border width to 0, but for some reason, the adjusted width is of cells at the end of the rows

```
 if (cell.raw === undefined) {
    cell.raw = '';
    cell.styles.lineWidth = 0;
  }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

So, after much thinking, I just came with an answer myself, not pretty, but it's working as I need it

My issue in the end was, that row lines where still being painted on on spanned rows, and setting the `lineWidth` on those cells which `raw` was `undefined` meaning those where the cells missing due to the span.

So, I just needed a way to identify those hidden cells due to the span on my table and remove it's `lineWidth`. To do this, I adjusted my `GetTableJSON` function so when I'm encountered with a cell that has the `display:hidden` css, I set it's value to `'hidden'`

```
for (var i = 1; i < tableElem.rows.length; i++) {
    var tableRow = tableElem.rows[i];
    var style = window.getComputedStyle(tableRow);
    if (includeHiddenElements || style.display !== 'none') {
      var rowData = [];
      for (var j in Object.keys(columns)) {
        var cell = tableRow.cells[j];
        style = window.getComputedStyle(cell);
        var val;
        if (style.display !== 'none') {
          val = cell ? cell.hasChildNodes() && cell.childNodes[0].tagName !== undefined ? cell.childNodes[0].textContent + (cell.getAttribute("rowSpan") ? "*" + cell.getAttribute("rowSpan") : '') : cell.textContent.trim() : '';
          cellsStyle[(i - 1) + "-" + j] = cell ? cell.hasChildNodes() && cell.childNodes[0].tagName !== undefined ? AdjustStyleProperties(window.getComputedStyle(cell.childNodes[0])) : AdjustStyleProperties(window.getComputedStyle(cell)) : {};
        } else {
            val = 'hidden'; 
        }
        rowData.push(val);
      }
      rows.push(rowData);
    }
```

And when drawing the cells, just set the `lineWidth` to 0 and returned a false in order to not write the value

```
drawCell: function(cell, data) {
      if (cell.raw === undefined)
        return false;
        if (cell.raw === 'hidden') {
        cell.styles.lineWidth = 0;
        return false;
      }
      if (cell.raw.indexOf("*") > -1) {
        debugger;
        var text = cell.raw.split("*")[0];
        console.log(text);
        var times = parseInt(cell.raw.split("*")[1]);
        doc.rect(cell.x, cell.y, cell.width, cell.height * times, 'DF');
        doc.autoTableText(text, cell.x + cell.width / 2, cell.y + cell.height / 2 * times, {
          halign: 'center',
          valign: 'middle'
        });
        return false;
      }
    }
```

This gave me the result I'm expecting, both color and printer friendly
[image: Color version]

[image: Printer friendly version]

In the meantime, this works for me, but somehow, I don't think I need to do this in order to have it working, as the example doesn't show doing anything of the likes in order to make the rowspan and colspan works

Regards!